# find failed rows from string using preg_match PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to wright regex using preg_match in PHP to do next:

I do have string like this:

test1:OK
test2:OK
test3:FAILD
test4:PROGRESS
test5:OK

so I need to find rows which are no OK..
test3:FAILD
test4:PROGRESS

so I think I have to check string between **:** and **\r\n (\n)** if != OK, how do I do this using preg_match?

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use regex?  String functions should be just fine for this; regexs are more of a last resort.

```
$lines = explode("\n", str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $lines));
$failed = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'OK') === false) {
        $failed[] = $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about that?  You can filter it directly down to which rows failed.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all('/test\d+:(?!OK)/', $allrows, $rowsNotOk)`

Comment: preg_match_all('/test\d+:(?!OK)/', $allrows, $rowsNotOk), can I do something like preg_match_all('/:(?!OK)/', $allrows, $rowsNotOk), do not wanna tied to test in the beginning of the row. could be something else like 1t:OK

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly valid. But I don't know exactly what do you want to store in the array.

Comment: i want to store row that does not have OK after **:**

Comment: preg_match_all('/^.*?(?=:(?!OK$))/', $allrows, $rowsNotOk) that will store the row names that do not end with "OK".

Comment: does not work for me. Getting Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test1
        )

)

Comment: That's probably because there's no new line at the end of each row. Could you post your actual code?

Comment: do not have any code, just string form my post test1:OK\ntest2:OK\n and so on